# Finding the eigenvector of a 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to work on finding eigenvectors. For the following matrix,

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    b & 0 & -a \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    a & 0 & -b \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I get the system
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
bx-az=0 \\ 
ax-bz=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

which becomes $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{a}{b}$. Because it was part of a larger question, I know
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}

is a solution. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $x=0, y=1, z=0$ into the equations,

\begin{align}
b\cdot0-a\cdot0=0\\
a\cdot0-b\cdot0=0
\end{align}

we see that it fulfills the conditions. Hence it is a solution.

If you multiply that vector to the original matrix, we can see that it is in the nullspace, the corresponding eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: Clear and concise! Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you multiply your matrix by the vector $(0,1,0)$, you get $0$ times the original vector, so $(0,1,0)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 0.

Answer (score 0):

The columns of a matrix are the images of the basis vectors. The second column of your matrix $A$ is zero, so you know at a glance that $(0,1,0)^T$ is a solution to $A\mathbf x=0$.